# Concatenate two or more lines without getting some duplicate at the last one

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to concatenate two or more lines if they don't start with 0000 and put those lines at the line that start with 00000 and add a |. This is code I'm using, it is working fine, but I'm getting the last line, some kind of duplicate of the values, but just the last one. Can anyone help me?

```
with open('TodasPGDAS.txt', 'r+', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    text = str();
    for line in file:
        if line[0:5] == "00000":
            text = text + '\n'
        text = text + '|' + line.strip()
    file.seek(0)
    file.write(text)
```

Comment: You seem to be writing back out over a file that already had content in it. If the new content is shorter than the old one, some of the previous lines will still appear. Also `;` aren't needed in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple and convenient refactoring which uses the `fileinput` module's `inplace` mode to replace the file's contents.

```
import fileinput

for file in fileinput.input(['TodasPGDAS.txt'], inplace=True):
    accumulated = []
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith("00000") and accumulated:
            print('|'.join(accumulated))
            accumulated = []
        accumulated.append(line.strip())
    if accumulated:
        print('|'.join(accumulated))
```

This also refactors the logic to only add `|` *between* fields. I'm guessing this is what you actually want; if not, perhaps you can clarify your question with a simple example input and expected output.

The default encoding in Python 3 should be UTF-8 on any sane platform.

Comment: I wanna add | between the lines I´m merging. For example, AAAA (line1) BBBB(Line2) Combine lines (AAAA|BBBB). I will test your code, thanks =)

Comment: Again, please edit your question. The syntax error will also need to be sorted out, as already remarked in a separate comment.